# Using unique values of column as higher level column pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Imagine I have a pandas dataframe as the following:

```
Side   Year   Value 1   Value 2
A      2020    56          5%
B      2019    24          3%
B      2018    42          4%
B      2020    414         31%
A      2019    421         51%
```

I would like to have something like this:

```
            A                 B
Year  Value1 Value2    Value1   Value2  
2018     -     -         42      4%
2019    421   51%        24      3%
2020     56    5%        414     31%
```

I tried creating side as an index and then transposing, but then I don't have the unique values but I get repeated values.

Comment: Both are shown above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a combination of [set index](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html), along with [unstack](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) and finally a [sort index](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html) to reshape your data :

```
res = df.set_index(["Year", "Side"]).unstack().swaplevel(1, 0, axis=1).sort_index(axis=1)

#remove axis details
res.columns.names = (None, None)

#reset to lowest level (-1)

res.reset_index(col_level=-1)

                      A                   B
      Year    Value 1   Value 2   Value 1   Value 2
  0   2018    NaN        NaN       42.0        4%
  1   2019    421.0      51%       24.0        3%
  2   2020    56.0       5%        414.0       31%
```

Comment: This is nearly perfect! Year becomes an index, could it just remain as a row?

Comment: you could add a `.reset_index` to the code; this exits Year as an index and back to a column

Comment: If I do that it takes all the way up to where side is for some reason

Comment: @AntonioLópezRuiz   edited the code. hope it suffices